# How to take Date Time information from Phone Settings? (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my Windows Phone Application I use Current Date and Time. How can I take Time and Date from Phone Settings Device, so when user is situated in another Counrty his Date Time would be differens?

**UPDATED**

So, how can I make my Date and Time absolute?

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly the question... shouldn't `DateTime.Now` work?

Comment: Look at `DateTime.Now` and `DateTime.UtcNow`. If user changes time zone - first will changes also, but second not. If user changes his time - both times will change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`, that's the best structure to handle datetime + timezone.